# Pull down a pin output at the same time set as Z state VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

When I set a pin in 'Z' state it keeps the state it has before.

For example:

```
if rising_edge(Clock) then
   counter <= counter + 1;
   case counter is
      when 0 =>
        PIN <= '0';
      when 1 =>
        PIN <= 'Z';
      others =>
   end case;
end process;
```

If I execute this code I'll have PIN set at '0' in 'Z' state.

```
if rising_edge(Clock) then
   counter <= counter + 1;
   case counter is
      when 0 =>
        PIN <= '1';
      when 1 =>
        PIN <= 'Z';
      others =>
   end case;
end process;
```

If I execute this code I'll have PIN set at '1' in Z state.

What I need is to have PIN set to '0' in Z state regardless of the state it was before. But I need to accomplish this without using an additional clock cycle to set PIN from '1' to '0' and then to 'Z'. Is that possible?

Comment: How did you verify it? Simulation? Hardware? If simulation, which simulator? Which hardware platform?

Comment: Do you understand that the signal assign to `counter` by `<=` has the effect that the new value is not seen by `case counter is` until the next cycle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an FPGA pin to be tristated, but also have a pulldown, you must set up the pulldown in your toolchain's pin configuration tool. I'm not aware of any FPGA toolchain that will infer a pulldown from assignment to `'L'`, which appears to be what you want (tristate with pulldown seems equivalent to 'weak low'). If you are running simulation only, try setting `PIN <= 'L'`.